# Change behavior of mouse buttons - do I have to write a driver? (Sharkoon Drakonia)

Tags: button, mouse, driver

I just bought a Sharkoon Drakonia (just for information). It has 11 buttons, but only two of them (except left, right and middle button of course) can be used as 4th and 5th mouse button (eg. in games), the other ones can only be modified to behave like a double click etc. via the configurator software shipped with the mouse. So I wondered if there is a way to completely change or remap (some of) the mouse buttons to be recognized in games as for example "Mouse 6" and "Mouse 7". I think I have to write a driver for it, am I right? Is there another way to achieve my aim?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to write a new driver - you can use some input remapping software like **GlovePie** (google for it). It has its own scripting language to program how input works. Most people use it to make console controllers behave like a mouse, keyboard or combination of both... But I've used it to make things kinda like what you want.

There are other software like GlovePie that can also do the job, but it's the only one whose name I can remember right now.

**edit:** I've just read your question more carefully. You may not be able to make a software see a *mouse6* or *mouse7*, but you can bind some action in a game to a key in the keyboard, and then map your extra mouse buttons to be seen as if they are those keys. It works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, it would be possible to bind a keyboard key to the extra mouse buttons.
I tested GlovePie, but the problem is that the extra buttons aren´t recognized.

Comment: Well, then probably it IS a driver problem - or maybe a hardware design issue. Those buttons probably don't send a signal to the motherboard saying that a given mouse button was pressed. I think instead of that they send some other input combination, in effect doing the same thing that GlovePie does :(